# How to Start Windows Service As Administrator Privileges

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows-services

I have my own application server which is windows service who communicates with the sql server, in some cases sql server service is stop so I am stating that via this code

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS");
sc.Start();
sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
```

but it requires administrator privileges to start service how can I start my window service as administrator

Comment: Have you tried running the application which starts the service as an administrator?

Comment: but both applications are the windows service. how can i run my windows service as administrator.

Comment: i just add this tag in my app.manifest file  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> it works ...

Comment: Then write it as an answer so this question will not be seen as unanswered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i just add this tag in my app.manifest file
`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
it works ...

Comment: VS2022 can generate the base file. The comments tell you how to configure this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073093/modify-manifest-file-win32-visual-studio-2022

Answer (score 6):

Lets split everything into steps

1. Add file "Application Manifest File" to you root catalog
2. Select project properties
3. In application tab Recources group find Manifest field
4. Paste you new manifest file name. Probably "app.manifest"
5. Fill file with this info

All information could be a little bit different based on you situation.
[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
        <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```