# How to force C# windows service to execute with admin privileges automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, console-application, user-permissions

I have a console application written in C#/.NET. I use this application as a windows service. This windows service needs to have admin privileges to execute its logic.

What I did was adding to my project an 'app.manifest' file as following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I also configured properties of the 'app.manifest' in two different ways as following and then compiled and published my project:

**Config1:**
**Build Action**: None
**Copy to Output Directory**: Copy Always

**Config 2:**
**Build Action:** Embedded Resource
**Copy to Output Directory:** Copy Always

However, when I install this application as a windows service and execute it, it fails due to lacking admin privileges. I can still introduce the admin credentials through the 'Properties->LogOn' panel of the windows service, but I want to avoid this step and force the service to execute with admin privileges by default.

Can you please help?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in the manifest, a service logon account with the requisite rights is still required (builtin `LocalSystem` service account will do). How are you installing the service? [ServiceProcessInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller?view=netframework-4.8) allows you to specify the logon account programmatically

Comment: Do you think that this _I want to avoid this step and force the service to execute with admin privileges by default._ makes any sense from a security standpoint?

Comment: I create the service using 'sc create ServiceName BinPath='Myexecutable' command in cmd and then start it. The thing is that I do not want to put admin credentials manually in the LogOn window. I just want to tell the windows service(programmatically) or by other means to 'execute as administrator'.

Comment: Please check below link [How to Start Windows Service As Administrator Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818247/how-to-start-windows-service-as-administrator-privileges)